# размер элемента Container в элементе Container

Tags: flutter, dart

Если в виджете Container родителе указать выравнивание

> alignment: Alignment.topLeft,

тогда все отрисовывается, как и задумано: часть кода + фото

```
@override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Container(
   width: 250,
   height: 250,
   color: Colors.orangeAccent,
   alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
   child: Container(
    width: 50,
    height: 50,
    color: Colors.pink,
   ),
  );
 }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если в виджете Container родителе не указать выравнивание

> //alignment: Alignment.topLeft,

тогда все отрисовывается **СОВСЕМ НЕ ТАК**, как и задумано, дочерний виджет Container растягивается на всю ширину и высоту родительского. Теоретически, он должен прижаться к верхнему левому углу и сохранить свои размеры.

: часть кода + фото

```
@override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Container(
   width: 250,
   height: 250,
   color: Colors.orangeAccent,
   //alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
   child: Container(
    width: 50,
    height: 50,
    color: Colors.pink,
   ),
  );
 }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `If the widget has no child and no alignment, but a height, width, or constraints are provided, then the Container tries to be as small as possible given the combination of those constraints and the parent's constraints` - если верить Google-переводчику, то здесь сказано, что высота и ширина учитываются вместе с остальными параметрами. Другими словами, ширина и высота может быть не такой, как указано в коде

Comment: Еще добавлю к ответу @Дмытрык. Родитель задает параметры для ребенка. То-есть, он правильно делает, что растягивается на всю ширину родителя.

Comment: Мое очень субъективное мнение, это аморально. Если у ребенка заданы размеры, они должны быть естественно  сохранены. Вот если бы их не было, тогда да. И я не понимаю, почему отсутствие параметра alignment, так кардинально все меняет. Теоретически, если оно явно отсутствует, зачит должно быть како-то значение по умолчанию.